# set value of slider with if else

Tags: jquery, slider

I have something like this

```
$maxvalue = ($data['any'] > 0 ? $site['any'] : $site['any']);
```

I want to set the max value in slider according to above query, here is code of slider

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>jQuery UI Slider - Range with fixed maximum</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider({
                        range: "max",
                        min: 10,
                        max: 60,
                        value: 10,
                        slide: function( event, ui ) {
                            $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
                        }
                });
                $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider( "value" ) );
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            <label for="amount">Minimum number of bedrooms:</label>
            <input type="text" id="amount" style="border: 0; color: #f6931f; font-weight: bold;" />
        </p>
        <div id="slider-range-max"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I do this? If there is any other slider code please post.

---

I got this working using

```
max: "<?php echo $maxvalue; ?>",
```

Now how can I get slider value after submit?

Edit- no reply, well i found answer myself 
Just change this

```
<input type="text" id="amount" style="border: 0; color: #f6931f; font-weight: bold;" />
```

Into

```
<input type="text" id="cpc" name="cpc" style="border: 0; color: #f6931f; font-weight: bold;" />
```

you can set name=any value and get this value by POTS_ on other page just like forum submit.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer to this question, when you can.  It prevents people from spending time where a solution is already found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using this

```
$maxvalue = any query ;
max: "<?php echo $maxvalue; ?>",
```